# Crystal Reports 11.5.10.1263 - tracing the source of a 'Database Field' object

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 11.5.10.1263.

I am not a regular Crystal Reports user but have used it in the past.

A Crystal Report [*that was recently modified by a third party*] works on our Production server but will not run on a Test Server [*with a Test Database that should, but may not, be identical to the Production SQL Server DB*]. I am tasked with figuring out why it will not work.

I initially opened the report in our production GUI and viewed the SQL using Menu Items 'Database' - 'Show Query'. I ran that SQL in SSMS and it gives a two-column list of Customer IDs and Customer Rep IDs.
I expected the SQL to show all the fields displayed in the report when it runs.

*When I've done this in the past, I have invariably got the full SQL that returns all fields shown in the report output.*

Guessing that some object built into the report uses those two values to retrieve the rest of the Customer details that the report output shows, I looked under 'Database Fields' in *Design View of the report in Crystal Reports* and where I expect a Table or View name, there is an object name [let's name it 'Unknown_Object'] that does not exist in our database ... with a long list of fields that I recognize and could probably find in our database by querying the different tables that they reside in.

The problem that I am trying to solve, however, is why the report runs in our Production GUI
on the Production Server/Environment and not in the Test GUI on our Test Server - which uses a 'replica' of the Production DB.

I believe that the reason is that 'Unknown_Object' is possibly some SQL [Stored Procedure? Function? Other Mechanism?] that I don't know how to examine - and that exists on the Production GUI and/or DB but not in the Test GUI and/or DB.

Q 1. Is it possible that 'Unknown_Object' is a 'black box' object that only the developer can view?

Q 2. What steps can I take to find out exactly what mechanism is being used to pull in all the Customer details using the Customer IDs and Customer Rep IDs that I was able to get at ... and thereby possibly answer the question about why it will not run on the Test System?

I hope I've explained with sufficient clarity.
I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the rpt file to your production server, and try to Verify Database. If CR says the database was updated, the queries in production and test environment can be different either in field types, their order, or something else.

Make sure the query on both servers return exactly the same data sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the old and the new reports using this tool http://r-tag.com/Pages/CrystalSearch.aspx. The tool has trial period, so no need to purchase.